# What does $f \in C^{2,1}$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis, notation

As in the title, what does the symbol $C^{2,1}$ stand for in the expression $f \in C^{2,1}$?

I found such notation in [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/imrn/article/2020/17/5387/5054619) by Ghomi and Spruck. I bet it is a stronger condition than $f \in C^{2}$, but I could not find a definition.

EDIT: In the paper, the function $f$ is defined to be an isometric immersion of a Riemannian surface into $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. In coordinates, this is a map $U \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$, where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Comment: $C^2$ means twice differentiable with $f''$ continuous. I'm guessing $C^{2,1}$ means twice differentiable with $f''$ Lipschitz.

Comment: Analysis is full of multi-superscript notations that do not have fully standard meanings and this is a good example of that. The above comment is a good guess but not the only conceivable one. It may help to specify the domain/codomain of $f$ (if these spaces have additional structure, this structure may provide clues) or even a reference to the paper.

Comment: Are you studying stochastic calculus and Ito's formula? Is f a function of two variables? In that case $f\in C^{2,1}$ means $C^2$ in the first variable and $C^1$ in the second

Comment: Which paper are you reading? Can you give a link?

Comment: Here is a link to the paper: https://academic.oup.com/imrn/article/2020/17/5387/5054619

Comment: Looks like a Lipschitz condition! See first paragraph of Section 4, "Unique Continuation," for context. But note that $f$ is a map from a Riemannian surface into $\mathbb{R}^3$ and not e.g. a real valued function of a single variable, so the notation in a textbook that would define these notions in greater detail, if you are looking for more, might be more complicated than the $f$ and $f''$ that you would often see in the single variable context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on context. If you found this notation in reference to a partial differential equation or similar real analysis setting, it most likely means that $f \in C^2$ and $f''$ is Lipschitz. This is a special case of the notation $f \in C^{2,\alpha}$ to mean $f \in C^2$ and $f''$ is $\alpha$-Holder continuous. Note that $\alpha=1$ in the definition of Holder continuity just gives the definition of Lipschitz continuity.

If you found this notation in a stochastic analysis setting, it most likely means that $f = f(x, t), x \in \mathbb{R}^n, t \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ and $\partial_{x_i}\partial_{x_j} f$ is continuous for any $i,j$ and $\partial_{t} f$ is continuous. That is, "$f$ is $C^2$ in space and $C^1$ in time."